# Is there any way to control how Crashlytics aggregates crashes?

Tags: c++, crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric

Crashlytics automatically aggregates crashes where the stack trace is similar. But for example we are using std::optional, where the bottom of the stack will always be

```
0
libsystem_kernel.dylib  
__pthread_kill + 8
4
libc++abi.dylib 
default_terminate_handler() + 48
5   ParaShapr   
CLSTerminateHandler() + 4298200188
6   libc++abi.dylib 
std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib 
std::terminate() + 68
8   ParaShapr   
optional.hpp line 259
std::experimental::bad_optional_access::~bad_optional_access()
```

and Crashlytics will handle all the bad optional accesses as a single crash, despite this can happen anywhere for many different reasons.

Is there any way to control how Crashlytics aggregates crashes?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. There are times when our grouping algorithm isn't perfect, but there isn't a way to customize the algorithm.